# How to prevent ArgoCD to pull manifests if Gitlab-CI fails?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, argocd

I am using Gitlab, it stores my repo. I also use Gitlab-CI for some checks (like DaTree, Snyk or Checkov). ArgoCD is setup to deploy my Kubernetes manfiests which are pulled from Gitlab repo.

## Question:

**How can prevent ArgoCD to pull if some Gitlab-CI checks are failing?**

What comes into my mind was, simply mirroring the original repo or use specific branches, if checks are passing. Something like this:

```
                        ┌──────────────────────────────────┐     ┌───────────┐
                        │Gitlab                            │     │K8s cluster│
                        │                  ┌───────────┐   │     │           │
       ┌─────┐     1    │  ┌─────────────┐ │ approved  │   │     │ ┌───────┐ │
       │ dev │───pushes─┼─▶│ Source repo │ │repo/branch│◀─4 pulls┼─│ArgoCD │ │
       └─────┘          │  └─────────────┘ └───────────┘   │     │ └───────┘ │
                        │      2 runs            ▲         │     │     │     │
                        │      tests             │         │     │ 4 deploys │
                        │         │             3          │     │     │     │
                        │  ┌─────────────┐   push if       │     │     ▼     │
                        │  │  Gitlab-CI  │────passed       │     │  ┌─────┐  │
                        │  └─────────────┘                 │     │  │Apps │  │
                        │                                  │     │  └─────┘  │
                        └──────────────────────────────────┘     └───────────┘
```

Is this "the way" how to do this, or are there some "tools" in ArgoCD or Gitlab to achieve approvals?

Comment: If the test fails.   
Did you stop CI/CD?

Comment: The CI fails (and stops). But ArgoCD is still able to pull the HEAD of git, so there must be a mechanism to either prevent Argo to pull. My idea was, that Gitlab-CI clones or create a second branch where Argo pulls after a successful run

Comment: In your diagram, ArgoCD pulls from `approved repo`. If CI fails (and stops), it will not push change to `approved repo`. This will result in your app still running the old version. Right?

Comment: yes, that was the initial idea. I thought maybe there is some option in ArgoCD or Gitlab-CI to handle such "blocker". But they more I think of it, they more I think I have answered my question in the question itself.

Comment: You can disable sync in ArgoCD app to not update the changes.

Comment: Yeah, but it should be kind of "automated".